# How to do a frequency band?

Tags: matlab, audio, frequency

Here in this code i am doing a stft on my wav-file. There is no problem with that. At the beginning, i am defining my parameter, afterwards using my wav file and then applying the stft. Basically what i am doing is a real-time spectral analysis. Anyway my question is, how do i a frequency band? I want my signal to be separated in LOW/MEDIUM/HIGH. I want my vector to be saved, from 0-250 Hz in the LOW-Band, 250-5000 Hz in the MEDIUM-Band, 5-22.05k Hz in the HIGH-Band. I advise you, to try my code in Matlab, if you don't understand it. Just take any wav-file. Btw my signal is plotted in the variable "Yres". Any solution is appreciated!

```
NFA=2; % Number is used for plotting every 2nd picture
t_seg=0.05; % Length of segment in ms

fftlen = 4096; 
% Lenght of "fft",because our segment contains 2205 points

[y,fs]=audioread('UnchainMyHeart.wav');
% audioread = functions reads WAV-file
% y = A vector which contains my audio signal
% fs = sample frequency (44100)
% 'UnchainMyHeart' = WAV-file

t=linspace(0,length(y)/fs,length(y));
% linspace = Creating time vector
% 0 = Start time
% length(y)/fs = End time
% length(y) = Number of samples in y

plot(t,y)
% plotting signal in the time domain


segl =floor(t_seg*fs); 
% Applying fft function on the variable "segl"

windowshift=segl/2; 
% Defining the size of the window, which goes to the next "segl"


window=hann(segl); 
% hann function

window=window.'; 

si=1; 
%Start index

ei=segl; 
%End index

AOS= length(y)/windowshift - 1;
% AOS is the number of "segl" we use (About 433)

f1=figure;
% Opening new window

f=0:1:fftlen-1;
f=f/(fftlen-1)*fs;
% Defining frequency vector

Ya=zeros(1,fftlen);

plot(f,Ya),axis([0 fs -90 50])

grid on 

n=0;
%start variable

for m= 1:1:AOS


y_a = y(si:ei);
y_a= y_a.*window;
Ya=fft(y_a, fftlen);

n=n+1;
if n==1
  Yres=abs(Ya);
  else
  Yres=Yres+abs(Ya);
end

if n==NFA
  Yres=Yres/NFA;
  n=0;

  drawnow; 
  %Tut die Grafikobjekte immer auf den neuesten Stand updaten

figure(f1);
plot(f(1:end/2), 20*log10(abs(Yres(1:end/2))));


ylim([-90 50]);
title('Spektrum eines Audiosignal');    
xlabel('f(Hz)');
ylabel('dB');

grid on;

end


si=si+windowshift; 
% Updating start index

ei=ei+windowshift; 
% Updating end index

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the best answer! But this may help you get started on something. You can use spectrogram() function from MATLAB's Signal Processing Toolbox.

Let's suppose you have an audio file named ''UnchainMyHeart.wav'(in your case) with one channel. The code goes as follows:

```
% Reading the audio file
[y1,fs] = audioread('UnchainMyHeart.wav');

% Parameters for STFT (or spectrogram)
windowDuration = 30e-3; overlapDuration = 15e-3;
windowLength = round(windowDuration*fs);   % window length
overlapLength = round(overlapDuration*fs); % overlapping of windows
nfft = 1024;

% Executing STFT for the signal
[S1,F1,T1,P1] = spectrogram(x1,hanning(windowLength), ...
overlapLength, nfft, fs, 'yaxis');
```

S1 and P1 contain STFT and Power Spectrum Density(PSD) of the signal for a time interval of each section with a time interval whose estimations are contained in T1.

**For your question,** you are looking for F1 which is a vector of cyclical frequencies expressed in terms of sampling frequency, fs. For example: if you have a sampling frequency of 48 kHz (fs) and nfft of 1024, then you will have 513 [(1024/2) +1)] frequency values spaced by (fs/nfft). i.e. 46.875. So your frequency components will be 0, 46.875, 46.875*2, ..., 46.875*512. The maximum you will have is 24 kHz due to Nyquist criterion.

Now, you can easily write a simple routine specifying the ranges as you said. The same technique can be used in your code which is an implementation of stft. I would suggest using MATLAB's built-in function unless your problem requires an implementation. Hope this helps!

If needed, I can answer why the parameters for STFT are chosen as included in the code.

Comment: My fs is 44.1k.I think i understand what you mean. (English is not my mother language). I am aware there is already a built in function for the stft. But i should have mentionend, that this is for a project and i am required to make the code myself, without using the built-in function. Is it perhaps possible, if you can show/explain me, how to specify the range? I am little bit troubled, how to apply it.

Comment: This is a common case of frequency resolution (works for both fft and stft). If you have fs = 44.1 kHz, your maximum frequency captured will be 22050.

Comment: If you have fs = 44.1 kHz, the maximum frequency captured will be 22050. With a frequency resolution of 4096, you will have frequencies spaced by 44.1e3/4096 = 10.7666 & 2049 values in STFT. So frequency vector will be: 0, 10.7666, 21.5332, 32.2998,...22050. In you case, STFT(1:24) will be for low-band, STFT(25:465) will be for med-band, the rest is for high-band. I hope you get it. STFT is the variable where you save your value of results.

Comment: Now i got it and thank you for explaining it very precisly :) I really appreciate your help!